# How can I catch a 404 error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I have an HTML audio element and I am dynamically setting the "src" property of the element to an audio file stored on our local area network.

This is how it works:

```
function setSource(source) {
   audio.src = source;
}

var audio = new Audio();
var source = "http://localhost/folder/file.mp3";
setSource(source);
```

Sometimes, the source audio file that I am pointing to has a broken link and this causes a 404 error to be generated and logged to the browser console.

[image]

I want to be able to catch the 404 errors so as to prevent them being logged to the console.

This is how I attempted it:

```
function setSource(source) {
  try {
    audio.src = src;
  }//end try
  catch (e) {
    //do nothing
  }//end catch
}//end setSource

var audio = new Audio();
var source = "http://localhost/folder/file.mp3";
setSource(source);
```

Unfortunately, my try/catch statement does absolutely nothing and the error is still logged to the console. Am I doing something wrong?

Due to the nature of my app, there will be lots of 404 errors, which is normal and expected, but it looks really unstable and "ugly" to the users (if they happen to open the console).

FYI: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent people checking error inside google chrome console, if it's an error, google will log it

Comment: Due to the nature of my app, there will be lots of 404 errors, which is normal and expected, but it looks really unstable and "ugly" to the users (if they happen to open the console) - I have added this into the body of my question :)

Comment: @guest271314 - will a ServiceWorker prevent the network request from being logged?

Comment: to "assure" the user, you could have an `error` event listener on the audio object, and log something assuring to the console :p

Comment: @JaromandaX No.

Comment: @guest271314 - I think the OP doesn't want to avoid the errors as such, just wants a clean console - which is impossible as network requests (with response status) will always be logged

Comment: @JaromandaX One option would be to call `console.clear()` if `status` of response is `404`. Or use a proxy server to make a `HEAD` request for the resource and checking the response headers before setting `HTMLMediaElement` `.src` to the URL

Comment: yep, but that doesn't always do anything, depending on the users options (in Chrome at least) - I'd be suspicious of a site that clears the console - besides, it doesn't clear the network tab :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Then requirement is not possible, yes? That is without using a proxy server, for example `YQL`

Comment: a proxy server is only necessary if the end server is not under the OP's control. If the end server **is**, then a proxy server is not at all necessary :p

Answer (score 9):

In this case, the logging of HTTP errors in the browser console is a feature exclusive to the browser and not of Javascript, or any other website code.

This cannot be prevented.

Answer (score 3):

```
audio.onload = function() {
    console.log('success');
};
audio.onerror = function() {
    console.log('fail');
};
audio.src = 'http://localhost/folder/file.mp3';
```

Comment: This logs "fail" to the console as well as the standard error.

Comment: you can make it log "the above error is nothing to worry about, keep calm and continue browsing" - or something equally assuring to the end user :p you can't hide network requests from the end user, that could be a perceived "security" or "privacy" issue by the end user

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With recent updates this is possible. You can enable it here: DevTools->Settings->General->Console->Hide network messages.

[image]
[How can I catch a 404 error in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45581361/10934118)